# How can I make Box2D create only one instance of a body?

Tags: c++, box2d, testbed

I only called the body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef) once but the Testbed keeps on creating bodies. Here is my code:

```
#ifndef FOOTEST_H
#define FOOTEST_H
#define DEGTORAD 0.0174532925199432957f
#define RADTODEG 57.295779513082320876f    

class FooTest : public Test
    {
        public:
        FooTest() { } //do nothing, no scene yet

        void Step(Settings* settings)
        {
            //run the default physics and rendering
            Test::Step(settings);

        b2BodyDef myBodyDef;
        myBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        myBodyDef.position.Set(0, 20);
        b2Body *dynamicBody = m_world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);

        b2PolygonShape polygonShape;
        b2FixtureDef myFixtureDef;
        myFixtureDef.shape = &polygonShape;
        myFixtureDef.density = 1;

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        b2Vec2 pos(sinf(i*90*DEGTORAD), cos(i*90*DEGTORAD));
        polygonShape.SetAsBox(1, 1, pos, 0);
        dynamicBody->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
        }


        myBodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
        myBodyDef.position.Set(0, 0);

        b2Body *staticBody = m_world->CreateBody(&myBodyDef);

        b2EdgeShape edgeShape;
        edgeShape.Set( b2Vec2(-15,0), b2Vec2(15,3) );

        myFixtureDef.shape = &edgeShape;
        staticBody->CreateFixture(&myFixtureDef);
        }

        static Test* Create()
        {
            return new FooTest;
        }
    };  
#endif
```

I was following this tutorial: 
[iForce2D](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/fixtures)
The tutorial's screenshots show just one instance of the created fixture. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Testbed" calls `Step` repeatedly, and you're creating instances in each call.
Note that the tutorial does all setup in the `FooTest` constructor, so it's only run once.

You've moved the setup from the constructor to the `Step` function for some reason.
Just a bit earlier in that tutorial, it says "if you are not doing anything special for rendering or physics control, you don't need to override Step()".